# I need to print only the if condition in kotlin android

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to android kotlin, I have an activity to display only the rows having (country code = 1) from the table, i have mentioned the same in the if condition, but its printing all the values in the table.

**Here is my activity code**

```
  package com.tripbegins.tripapp

 import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.ViewGroup
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.visa_details_description.view.*


 class VisaView(val visafeed: Homefeed): 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomVisaViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return visafeed.visa.count()

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CustomVisaViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
    val valueRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.visa_details_description, parent, false)
    return CustomVisaViewHolder(valueRow)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomVisaViewHolder?, position: Int) {

    val visaDescription = visafeed.visa.get(position)

      if (visaDescription.country_id == 1) {

            holder?.visaDescriptionView?.description_view?.text = visaDescription.description

        }

 }

 }

 class CustomVisaViewHolder(val visaDescriptionView: View?) : 
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder(visaDescriptionView) {

 }
```

Recylerview of the activity

```
 package com.tripbegins.tripapp

 import android.content.Context
 import android.graphics.Color
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
 import android.os.Bundle
 import android.support.v7.widget.*
 import android.view.LayoutInflater
 import android.view.View
 import android.view.ViewGroup
 import com.google.gson.Gson
 import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
 import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_horizontal_scroll.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.visa_layout.*
 import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.visa_layout.view.*
 import okhttp3.*
 import java.io.IOException

 class HorizontalScrollActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_scroll)

    recylerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

    val snapHelper:SnapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    //recylerView.adapter = AdoptorView()
    jsonfetch()

}

fun jsonfetch(){
    val url = "http://webmyls.com/tripapp/get_country_visa.php"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{

        override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            val homefeed = gson.fromJson(body, Homefeed::class.java)
            val visafeed = gson.fromJson(body, Homefeed::class.java)




            runOnUiThread{
                recyclerView.adapter = AdoptorView(homefeed)
                recylerView.adapter = VisaView(visafeed)
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
            println("failed to connect with json file")
        }

    })

}
 }

 class Homefeed (val country: List<countryName>, val visa:           
 List<visaDetails>){

 }

 class countryName ( val id: Int, val country: String) {

 public val imageTitleId = id
 }


 class visaDetails (val id: Int, val country_id : Int, val description:      String){


 }
```

**Table**

This is the json file to fetch the values for my output

```
 visa: [
 {
 id: "1",
 country_id: "1",
 description: "15 DAYS SINGLE ENTRY"
 },
 {
 id: "2",
 country_id: "1",
 description: "30 DAYS MULTI ENTRY"
 },
 {
 id: "4",
 country_id: "2",
 description: "30 DAYS SINGLE ENTRY"
 },
 {
 id: "5",
 country_id: "2",
 description: "90 DAYS SINGLE ENTRY"
 },
 {
 id: "6",
 country_id: "3",
 description: "21 Days Single Entry"
 },
 {
 id: "7",
 country_id: "3",
 description: "120 Days Single Entry"
 },
 {
 id: "8",
 country_id: "2",
 description: "30 Days Express Visa"
 },
 {
 id: "9",
 country_id: "2",
 description: "90 Days Express Visa"
 }
 ],
```

**My expected result**

The output should display only the values is equal to country code = 1

15 DAYS SINGLE ENTRY
30 DAYS MULTI ENTRY

**Current result**

Its displaying the country_code = 1 values along with all the rows

15 DAYS SINGLE ENTRY
30 DAYS MULTI ENTRY
30 days single entry
30 days single entry
30 days single entry
30 days single entry
30 days single entry
30 days single entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to show only the rows with `countryId==1`, then you should add to your `VisaView` (which is an `Adapter`, not a `View`) only the VISA matching that condition. What you are probably doing is to add **all** the rows (but you didn't provide the piece of code where you create the `VisaView`, so mine is just a guess).

### EDIT

Based on your code, one of the possible solution is the roughly the following:

1) Change the `VisaView` (should also be renamed to `VisaAdapter` or something like that since it is not a `View` but an `Adapter`) to hold the list of `VisaDetails`:

```
class VisaView(val visa: List<VisaDetails>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomVisaViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return visa.count()

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CustomVisaViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val valueRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.visa_details_description, parent, false)
        return CustomVisaViewHolder(valueRow)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomVisaViewHolder?, position: Int) {

        val visaDescription = visa[position]

        if (visaDescription.country_id == 1) {

            holder?.visaDescriptionView?.description_view?.text = visaDescription.description

        }

    }

}

class CustomVisaViewHolder(val visaDescriptionView: View?) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(visaDescriptionView) {

}
```

Change the instantiation of the `Adapter` to put only the VISA you want to show in the list:

```
recylerView.adapter = VisaView(visafeed.visa.filter { it.country_id == 1 }) // the "1" can and should be parameterized in case you need to reuse the code
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you please help me with the code to add the condition in Adapter.

Comment: could you please provide the code where you create the `VisaView` instance? One way of doing it should be something like `new VisaView(visafeed.visa.filter { it.country_id == 1 })` and you should also change your `VisaView` implementation to hold the collection of VISA instead of `Homefeed`. However this is not the only possible solution

Comment: I have another table 

country: [
{
id: "1",
country: "Malaysia"
},
{
id: "2",
country: "Dubai"
},
{
id: "3",
country: "Armenia"
},
{
id: "4",
country: "Georgia"
}
],

If i want to check the country_id (of table visa) = id ( of table country). Can you please provide a solution. @user2468312

Comment: when you read that table you need to save the country id into a variable. Then you will use that variable to `filter` the list of VISA in the second snippet I provided, instead of using the hardcoded value `1`. Otherwise you can do everything in SQL and retrieve only the VISA description you are interested in

Comment: I am new to Android. Could you please help with the code to check the values between two tables or in sql. Please do the needful. @user2468312